# How to call didReceiveRemoteNotification in didfinishlaunchingwithoptions Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, remote-notifications

How can I call the method didReceiveRemoteNotification in didfinishlaunchingwithoptions? I'm using swift language.
when the user directly opens the app, the notification cancelled and the operations performed in didReceiveRemoteNotification not called. How to handle this ?

I've reached upto here. But unable to complete

```
if let options = launchOptions, notification = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notification, fetchCompletionHandler: _______)

        }
```

Comment: @SausageMachine  
In didReceiveRemoteNotification I am saving this notification data. But when a notification came, app opened (without clicking the notification) , the notification automatically cancelled and save action is not performing

Comment: Its doesn't matter which language are you using Swift / Objective c but process will se same for Push notification. DidReceiveRemoteNotification method will call when push notification will receive and the tap on notification.

Comment: But when the user directly opens the app, the notification cancelled and the operations performed in didReceiveRemoteNotification not called. How to handle this ?

Comment: you can use local notifications.

Comment: @Anand  Notifications are send from server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per docs,

> The notification is delivered when the app isn’t running in the
>   foreground. In this case, the system presents the notification,
>   displaying an alert, badging an icon, perhaps playing a sound, and
>   perhaps displaying one or more action buttons for the user to tap.
>
> The user taps a custom action button in an iOS 8 notification. In this
>   case, iOS calls either
>   application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:
>   or
>   application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:.
>   In both methods, you get the identifier of the action so that you can
>   determine which button the user tapped. You also get either the remote
>   or local notification object, so that you can retrieve any information
>   you need to handle the action.
>
> The user taps the default button in the alert or taps (or clicks) the
>   app icon. If the default action button is tapped (on a device running
>   iOS), the system launches the app and the app calls its delegate’s
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, passing in the
>   notification payload (for remote notifications) or the
>   local-notification object (for local notifications). Although
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: isn’t the best place to
>   handle the notification, getting the payload at this point gives you
>   the opportunity to start the update process before your handler method
>   is called.
>
> For remote notifications, the system also calls the
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
>   method of the app delegate.
>
> If the app icon is clicked on a computer running OS X, the app calls
>   the delegate’s applicationDidFinishLaunching: method in which the
>   delegate can obtain the remote-notification payload. If the app icon
>   is tapped on a device running iOS, the app calls the same method, but
>   furnishes no information about the notification.
>
> The notification is delivered when the app is running in the
>   foreground. The app calls the
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: or
>   application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method of the app delegate.
>   (If application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
>   isn’t implemented, the system calls
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:.) In OS X, the system calls
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:.

You can find the link for the same in here :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

**Summary :**
You have to handle APNS in 3 situations :

1. **App is in Foreground/App is in background (but not suspended) :** application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method of the app delegate is called and payload is handed over to you.

2.**App is suspended/killed and user taps on notification or Alert:** application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: of app delegate gets called and you can access payload from launchOption.

3.**App is suspended/killed and user taps on App Icon** : You will not receive any info about APNS. Simplest solution you can do is once the app becomes active make a web service call to web server fetch all the updated info and update your UI and application badge count :)

Hope it helps :)